# Play Scala Json Transfomer : multiple arrays to single array of objects

Tags: json, scala, playframework

How to write a Json Transformer that converts

`{"id" : [1,2], "name":["a","b"]}`  to `idname:[ {id:1, name:"a"}, {id:2 , name:"b"}]`

I am following this guide for implementing transfomration https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonTransformers

Comment: Transformers convert case classes into json. You appear to want to turn json into different json ...

Comment: @CliveEvans  Json Transformers are precisely to transform givne json into another one. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonTransformers

Answer (score 0):

Writing the general case transformer can be difficult. Instead you can try reasoning through the standard Scala objects of `Map` and `List`. Here's a way to do it using `map` twice:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val a = Json.parse("""{"id" : [1,2], "name":["a","b"]}""").as[Map[String, List[JsValue]]]
val b = a.map {case (k, v) => v.map(k -> _)}
  .transpose
  .map(_.toMap)

Json.toJson(b)
// play.api.libs.json.JsValue = [{"id":1,"name":"a"},{"id":2,"name":"b"}]
```